# Texstudio inverse search stopped to work

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search

After performing Windows 10 maintenance inverse search does not work.
Texstudio version: 2.12.14.

The setting are as before:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem: directory name contained Cyrillic letters.

Comment: Make sure you will accept your own answer as soon as possible so that the question will not be bumped in the future.

Comment: OK it is the internal viewer using synctex so nothing to do with the image you gave NOTE synctex will work with any odd characters and names if the system settings allow it In a recent case of testing why a French e with accent kept disappearing it was a windows setting that made the difference the way to check is build a synctex file with -1 (non compressed) look at the header to check the characters are Cyrillic then set a simple responder such as echoargs or even plain windows notepad as the target for inverse search and see if it gets asked to open those characters

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the answer to this question, but it was the first result when I searched for mine.

I used the following code to highlight frames and to search for overfull boxes.

```
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
```

Removing it made the inverse search work again.